# Error running pod with image from gcr.io

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I've successfully [pushed my Docker container image to gcr.io](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/#pushing_to_the_registry) with the following command:

`$ gcloud docker push gcr.io/project-id-123456/my-image`

But when I try to [create a new pod](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/pods/single-container#creating_a_pod) I get the following error:

```
$ kubectl run my-image --image=gcr.io/project-id-123456/my-image
CONTROLLER  CONTAINER(S)  IMAGE(S)                           SELECTOR      REPLICAS
my-image    my-image      gcr.io/project-id-123456/my-image  run=my-image  1

$ kubectl get pods
NAME            READY  STATUS                                                                                                   RESTARTS   AGE
my-image-of9x7  0/1    Error pulling image (latest) from gcr.io/project-id-123456/my-image, Untar exit status 1 unexpected EOF  0          5m
```

It doesn't pull on my local as well:

```
$ docker rmi -f $(docker images -q) # Clear local image cache
$ gcloud docker pull gcr.io/project-id-123456/my-image:latest
…
Error pulling image (latest) from gcr.io/project-id-123456/my-image, Untar re-exec error: exit status 1: output: unexpected EOF
```

Can someone please suggest me how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after digging around in the Docker code base, I think I have found some similar reports of what you are seeing.

The way this error is displayed changed in 1.7, but this thread seems related:
   https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14792

This turned me onto this fix, which landed in 1.8:
   https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15040

In particular, see this comment:
   https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15040#issuecomment-125661037

The comment seems to indicate that this is only a problem for v1 layers, so our Beta support for v2 may work around this issue.

You can push to our v2 beta via:

   `gcloud docker --server=beta.gcr.io push beta.gcr.io/project-id-123456/...`

You can then simply change the reference in your Pod to "beta.gcr.io/..."  and it will pull via v2.

Comment: Is it going to be some announcement when v2 is GA? Docker is deprecating support on Docker Hub for clients version 1.5 and earlier: http://blog.docker.com/2015/10/docker-hub-deprecation-1-5/

Comment: There was an announcement earlier this week, `beta.gcr.io` should no longer be necessary.